# dnu restore returns path error ''/Users/<account name>/.dnx/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler/1.0.0-rc1-final' is denied.' on OS X

Tags: asp.net, macos, asp.net-core, coreclr

I've been trying to follow along the OS X ASP.NET 5 guide [Your first ASP.NET 5 Application on a Mac](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html).

I set up my environment following the [Installing ASP.NET 5 on Mac OS X](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html) guide using the command line and installing DNX for .NET Core.

Yeoman has successfully scaffolded my app and when I get to the next step and run `dnu restore` I get the following path error.

```
Restore failed
Access to the path
'/Users/simon/.dnx/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler/1.0.0
-rc1-final' is denied.
```

Full output from `dnu restore` is here: https://gist.github.com/simonneedham/aed410bbb31a98427164

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per chat with Victor below. The resolution was

Delete my entire `~/.dnx` folder and delete my `project.lock.json` file.

Make sure my .net execution environment is up to date. I was trying to run on coreclr so I ran `dnvm upgrade -r -coreclr`

Then run `dnu restore` to recreate the `.dnx` folder and the `packages` folder below. This time around the packages folder was re-created with regular permissions that didn't require elevation.

Comment: And the more time I've spent ASP.NET 5 on OS X my CLI workflow has become. 1. try command 2. If error then try sudo command.

Comment: You shouldn't need sudo for restore... You could try deleting the `packages` folder under `.dnx` and the restore again without sudo

Comment: Hmm didn't help sadly. I had to elevate just to delete 'packages' (In Finder it appears with a little no entry sign on the folder and when I deleted it I was prompted for password). After deleting, a plain 'dnu restore' still raises the same path exception as before. 'sudo dnu restore' works fine, recreates the packages folder, same locked permissions (no entry sign in Finder) as previously.

Comment: Try delete the entire `.dnx` folder or reset the permissions to it. Probably it was created by sudo and everything under it now requires sudo

Comment: Hey that's sorted it. Tks! I deleted my entire `~/.dnx` folder and I also deleted my `project.lock.json` file. I was then able to run `dnu restore` successfully. The `packages` folder was re-created with regular permissions.